# Data compaction in (My)SQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've got a table with 2 columns. The first one is the auto-increment one and the second holds some numeric value. I need to group rows in such a way: get N consecutive rows (using the auto-increment field), count average of corresponding numeric values and put this 1 new line to the other table. Can anyone help me with the GROUP BY statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for group by ?

```
SELECT floor(id / 5) cnt,avg(2ndcol) from <table> group by cnt;
```

This will get groups of 5 rows and return the average of `2ndcol`. Example http://www.sqlize.com/y4mTuDF1Cy

[avg() docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

edited as per comments

Comment: Sure this one will work, but I need to get not only 1..10 but 11..20, 21..30 and so on. Besides, if I need to group by 10 - it's easier to do -> I just need to add leading zeros and group by left(counter,length(counter)-1). Weird, but must work. But I need to group by 5 records and that's the problem :)

Comment: @DEgorov something like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113896/group-by-id-range -> example here -> http://www.sqlize.com/y4mTuDF1Cy